# Cannot open backup device '/home/ec2-user/db-name.bak'. Operating system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: linux, sql-server

Recently when I restore a database backup, I met a very strange issue. It failed when I restore from /homne/ec2-user/db-name.bak, and then succeeded when restore from /var/opt/mssql/backup/db-name.bak. Files at both locations the owner is the same ec2-user.

permissions:

`-rw-rw-r-- ec2-user ec2-user db-name.bak`

Command failed:

`RESTORE DATABASE fomv3 FROM DISK = '/home/ec2-user/db-name.bak' WITH MOVE 'db-name' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/db-name.mdf', MOVE 'db-name_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/db-name_Log.ldf`

Error: Cannot open backup device '/home/ec2-user/db-name.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Command succeeded:

`RESTORE DATABASE fomv3 FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/db-name.bak' WITH MOVE 'db-name' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/db-name.mdf', MOVE 'db-name_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/db-name_Log.ldf'`

RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed x pages in x seconds.

What's wrong with the file at /home/ec2-user/?

Answer (score 1):

The databases service is probably run under its own service user, not run under user `ec2-user`. The service user, whatever it is, would not have access to another user's home directory.
Like on Windows, you would have your Windows user for example `Dave`, but the SQL Server service in most cases would run as user `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` or some other user you specify during installation.

The query that you execute, is not executed by you, you just send the query to the service process, it's the service process which executes the query + access the bak file + restore you database.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some considerations if you are using the Microsoft SQL Server Linux containers.

Let's say you have the following containers running:

- Container A (based on mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest) hosts the database server.
- Container B (based on mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools) is used to execute the restore script using the `sqlcmd` tool.

Although `sqlcmd` inside Container B initiates the restore operation, the actual operation will be performed inside Container A by the database server. That means the `db-name.bak` file must be found inside Container A (e.g. `/var/opt/mssql/backup/db-name.bak)`, and not relative to a location inside Container B.